# How to query in a way that relates a name to an ID and then using that ID to sum up what comes under that ID

Tags: sql

I'm a student learning SQL. With querying, if you are given data that you have to relate to a primary key in the same table that will then be used to identify data in another table, how do you query that? **I only want a push in the right direction because I don't want to copy and paste someone's code.**

For example:
You are to find out how many staff are being managed by a manager and you are to find this by using the managers first and last name (which is not the primary key). The database is below. ManagerNo and StaffID are the same.

Branch (BranchNo, ManagerNo)
Staff (staffID, fName, lName, position, BranchNo)

Thank you for your time

Comment: Staff table should contain BranchNo as well to define how many employees are managed by a Manager. As per current setup, the count will show whole employee count of the organization (regardless Branch) for each manager.

Comment: @mkRabbani, thanks. I changed Deptno to BranchNo. My main problem still is the question asks it as is. When I try join these 2 table via inner join, I still run into the problem of how to use the first and last name of a manger in order to figure out how many staff he manages. SELECT COUNT(StaffNo), 
FROM Staff
INNER JOIN Branch
ON Staff.branchNo = Branch.branchNo
HAVING ?

Answer (score 0):

You would use two `join`s:

```
select s.*
from staff s join
     branch b 
     on s.BranchNo = b.BranchNo join
     staff sm
     on sm.staffId = b.ManagerNo
where sm.fname = ? and sm.lname = ?;
```